# Remove all .ica files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've tried a few different ways and still the same results it don't work.

```
remove-item .\*\appdata\local\temp\* -Include *.ica
```

I want it to remove all the .ica files in the users temp folder.

Comment: -include and -exclude only really work with -recurse. -filter should work just as well

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're looking for the users' temp folder. If you're looking for that you can find it with `$path = $env:temp` Use that for the $path that @kekimian used.

The finished product would look something like this:

```
$path = $env:temp
Get-ChildItem -path $path -Filter "*.ica" -Force -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Confirm:$False
```

Comment: get-ChildItem : Missing an argument for parameter 'Path'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String[]' and try again.

Here is what I get

Comment: it works but now I am getting a confirm message that pops up.

Comment: $path = $env:temp
Get-ChildItem -path $path -Filter "*.ica" |  where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Remove-Item -recurse -Force -Confirm:$true

Comment: No, the `-confirm` argument makes you confirm each deletion. `get-help remove-item -Parameter confirm`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$path = path to the folder
Get-ChildItem -path -Filter "*.ica" |  where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Remove-Item -Force -Confirm:$true
```

Comment: path to folder is the biggest issue. The path is %temp% but powershell doesn't seem to understand that path.

Comment: What is your target? One or multiple servers? Can you get users name from ad?

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying a root folder, getting a listing of files that match, and piping that list to `remove-item`:

`Get-ChildItem "c:\users\$username\appdata\local\temp\*.ica" -Force -Recurse | Remove-Item -Confirm:True`

-or-

`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\$username\appdata\local\temp" -Include '.ica' -Force -Recurse | Remove-Item -Confirm:True`

I think you need the `-Force` on `Get-ChildItem` because some of the path there includes hidden folders.  If it works without it, leave it out.

Edit:

```
foreach ($user in (Get-ChildItem -Directory C:\Users).name) { <#do stuff#> }
```

Also, `$ENV:Temp` in PowerShell is equivalent to `%TEMP%`.  There are many other Environment variables contained in `$ENV:`.

Or, if you need to do this for all users:

`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\" -Include '.ica' -Force -Recurse | Remove-Item -Confirm:True`

Comment: Neither one will work since this is something I will push out to the enterprise and I will not know the username. Also I am not able to use %temp% because powershell doesn't see that path.